# How can I query a DbSet so that it returns both Local and non-Local data

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I would like to query my Entity DbSet and get results from the Local context and the database as well.

I have this query:

```
Dim lResults = MyDbContext.MyEntity.Local.Where(Function(x) x.ParentId = lId)
```

But this only gives me results from previously loaded elements.

I want this to run a query on both the Local and non-local data.
I don't want to do a `MyDbContext.MyEntity.Load()`, since that loads all the rows from the DB, which can be thousands in my case.

**EDIT:**

I realized it was due to the fact that I actually did the following:

```
Dim lExpression = Function(x) x.ParentId = lId
Dim lResults = MyDbContext.MyEntity.Where(lExpression).ToList()
```

This way, is the expression somehow not evaluated?

**EDIT2:**

The problem was that I was using a Func and not an Epxression. The Func cannot be translated to SQL, so it retrieves the whole dataset and then filters it.

Comment: Why not do `MyDbContext.MyEntity.Where(Function(x) x.ParentId = lId).Load()` ?

Comment: `Error 196 'Load' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of MyEntity)'`


Though a ToList() does work, but it loads everything from the DB.

Comment: I don't understand. `MyEntity.Where` should return an `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Oszkar looks like you tried this `MyDbContext.MyEntity.Local.Where(Function(x) x.ParentId = lId).Load()` - of course that won't work, ***remove the Local***.

Comment: I actually tried it without the Local. Strange.

Comment: The error you posted in the comment above mentioned about `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` - that means the `Where` clause resolves to an `IEnumerable<...>` - that's impossible if your `MyDbContext.MyEntity` is a DbSet<...> (which implements IQueryable<..>).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a Func and not an Epxression. The Func cannot be translated to SQL, so it retrieves the whole dataset and then filters it.

The solution is:

```
Dim lExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of MyEntity, Boolean)) = Function(x) x.ParentId = lId
Dim lResults = MyDbContext.MyEntity.Where(lExpression).ToList()
```